# How to get ripple effect in Gesture Detector

Tags: flutter, dart, ripple-effect

I want to use the function `LongPressDown` which also gives `LongPressDownDetails` of `GestureDetector` but sadly, Gesture Detector comes without the ripple touch effect. So if I choose to use `InkWell` it doesn't have the LongPressDownDetails.

So my question is, how can I get the ripple effect of InkWell with the features of GestureDetector?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's pretty straightforward, just add an `Inkwell` over the `GestureDetector` and you'll be good to go (no need to write anything in the `onTap`).

```
return InkWell(
      onTap: () {},
      child: GestureDetector(
        onLongPress: (){
          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(const SnackBar(
          content: Text('Tap'),
        ));
        }
        ,
        child: const Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
          child: Text('Flat Button'),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Comment: It doesn't really work that well, the ripple effect won't show if use gesture detectors, onlong press and ontap

Comment: It is working for me though what is the code that you are using with this

Comment: I use onTap to navigate to another screen and onLongPressStart to show popup menu, but the thing is, it doesn't show the ripple effect, if i remove the gesture detector then it does show

Comment: I am really really sorry. I am such a fool. I forgot to add on tap inside the InkWell. Sorry to bother you and thank you so much for your answer.

Comment: No problems :) Is it working fine now? And please share some code next time so that we can also replicate the issue at our end.

Comment: Yes it is working now and I promise to include the code next time.